# Removing /product-category/ and /shop/ from URL in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, url, woocommerce, permalinks

I'm building an ecommerce store with WooCommerce, and I would like to change how my URLs are created. At the moment the structure is

```
domain.com/product-category/category-name
domain.com/shop/category-name/product-name
```

For SEO purposes would like to change it to

```
domain.com/category-name
domain.com/category-name/product-name
```

but when I delete the product category base in Wordpress permalink settings, it just reappears. Then I found [this page](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/removing-product-product-category-or-shop-from-the-urls/) stating that I shouldn't change it at all. Is that true? Am I wrong in wanting to alter the URLs?

If it's fine to change them, how can I do it?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I think this will help you.

Removing those URLs is one of the major improvements in search engine optimization for any online store because then search engines will not take into account the unnecessary words in the link. So, the search for your products will become more precise. I also encountered this problem and tested most of the plugins that were available on the WordPress website. Now I definitely can recommend Permalink Manager by Premmerce because it's a free, very user-friendly, and simple plugin.

Thanks.

Comment: I find it weird to come on Stack Overflow to get a question answered, and when I search for it, I get plugin suggestions instead of how to actually fix the problem. Woo-permalink-manager constantly hassles users to upgrade to their premium version.

Comment: This answer should be removed, it's promo for a paid plugin which doesn't work.